# Problem on Rails fixtures creation sequence

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rake

I am reading the book Simply Rails by Sitepoint and given these models:

story.rb

```
class Story < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates_presence_of :name, :link
    has_many :votes do
        def latest
            find :all, :order => 'id DESC', :limit => 3
        end
    end

    def to_param
        "#{id}-#{name.gsub(/\W/, '-').downcase}"
    end
end
```

vote.rb

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :story
end
```

and given this fixtures

stories.yml

```
one:
  name: MyString
  link: MyString

two:
  name: MyString2
  link: MyString2
```

votes.yml

```
one:
  story: one

two:
  story: one
```

these tests fail:

story_test.rb

```
def test_should_have_a_votes_association
    assert_equal [votes(:one),votes(:two)], stories(:one).votes
  end

def test_should_return_highest_vote_id_first
    assert_equal votes(:two), stories(:one).votes.latest.first
  end
```

however, if I reverse the order of the stories, for the first assertion and provide the first vote for the first assertion, it passes

story_test.rb

```
def test_should_have_a_votes_association
    assert_equal [votes(:two),votes(:one)], stories(:one).votes
  end

  def test_should_return_highest_vote_id_first
    assert_equal votes(:one), stories(:one).votes.latest.first
  end
```

I copied everything as it is in the book and have not seen an errata about this. My first conclusion was that the fixture is creating the records from bottom to top as it was declared, but that doesn't make any point

any ideas?

**EDIT**: I am using Rails 2.9 running in an RVM

Comment: I've never seen this error before (but I'm quite to ruby too). Have you tried to name the items in the fixture with less generic names? Specially the stories.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your fixtures aren't getting IDs 1, 2, 3, etc. like you'd expect - when you add fixtures, they get IDs based (I think) on a hash of the table name and the fixture name.  To us humans, they just look like random numbers.

Rails does this so you can refer to other fixtures by name easily.  For example, the fixtures

```
#parents.yml
vladimir:
  name: Vladimir Ilyich Lenin

#children.yml
joseph:
  name: Joseph Vissarionovich Stalin
  parent: vladimir
```

actually show up in your database like

```
#parents.yml
vladimir:
  id: <%= fixture_hash('parents', 'vladimir') %>
  name: Vladimir Ilyich Lenin

#children.yml
joseph:
  id: <%= fixture_hash('children', 'joseph') %>
  name: Joseph Vissarionovich Stalin
  parent_id: <%= fixture_hash('parents', 'vladimir') %>
```

Note in particular the expansion from `parent: vladimir` to `parent_id: <%= ... %>` in the child model - this is how Rails handles relations between fixtures.

Moral of the story:  Don't count on your fixtures being in any particular order, and don't count on `:order => :id` giving you meaningful results in tests.  Use `results.member? objX` repeatedly instead of `results == [obj1, obj2, ...]`.  And if you need fixed IDs, hard-code them in yourself.

Hope this helps!

PS:  Lenin and Stalin weren't actually related.

Comment: I'll wait for other answers, but I guess this is it pretty much. I mean the failure messages were pointing to the vote ids represented as string of digits. By hardcode IDs, do you mean I should provide them in the yml fixture files as well?

Comment: @Ygam  The failures were because you'd expect `votes(:one)` to have an ID of, say, 1, and `votes(:two)` to then have an ID of 2.  But instead, they both have (pseudo-)random IDs, the output of the hash function I mentioned.  And if `votes(:one).id` is 287829 and `votes(:two).id` is 108291, then the results of `Vote.all`, which will be ordered by ID (the default index), and _backwards_, as far as you're concerned.

To hardcode the IDs, put a line like `id: 1` in your YML fixtures.  Or, as I like to do, define the constant IDs in your model, and then use `id: <%= Parent::LENIN %>`, etc.  Cheers!

Comment: @XavierHolt How can I use the fixture_hash in rails console

Comment: @SriramR - It's been a while since I did Rails, but I think `fixture_hash` was just something I made up as an example.  The actual function seems to be [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb#L572).

Answer (score 1):

Xavier Holt already gave the main answer, but wanted to also mention that it is possible to force rails to read in fixtures in a certain order.

By default rails assigns its own IDs, but you can leverage the YAML `omap` specification to specify an ordered mapping

```
# countries.yml
--- !omap
- netherlands:
    id:         1
    title:      Kingdom of Netherlands
- canada:
    id:         2
    title:      Canada
```

Since you are forcing the order, you have to also specify the ID yourself manually, as shown above.

Also I'm not sure about this part, but I think once you commit to overriding the default rails generated ID and use your own, you have to do the same for all downstream references.

In the above example, suppose each country can have multiple leaders, you would have do something like

```
# leaders.yml
netherlands-leader:
  country_id: 1   #you have to specify this now!
  name: Willem-Alexander
```

You need to manually specify the id that refers to the previous Model (Countries)